# Синхронная прокрутка нескольких listbox winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

Есть 4 листбокса в winforms, количество айтемов там всегда одинаковое, как сделать синхронную прокрутку с клавиатуры(стрелок), колесика мышки и ползунка. Ползунок нужно оставить только на одном из листбоксов. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует подписаться на событие прокрутки на том ListBox на котором идёт прокрутка, а в обработчике этого события задавать значения **TopIndex** остальным спискам (значение должно быть такое же, как и у главного).

В нашем случае у ListBox из WinForms нет своего события скроллинга, поэтому будем улучшать наш список:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class BetterListBox : ListBox 
{
// Event declaration
    public delegate void BetterListBoxScrollDelegate(object Sender, 
    BetterListBoxScrollArgs e);
    public event BetterListBoxScrollDelegate Scroll;
    // WM_VSCROLL message constants
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
    private const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
    private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
    // Trap the WM_VSCROLL message to generate the Scroll event
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL) {
        int nfy = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF;
        if (Scroll != null && (nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK || nfy == SB_ENDSCROLL))
        Scroll(this, new BetterListBoxScrollArgs(this.TopIndex, nfy == SB_THUMBTRACK));
    }
}
public class BetterListBoxScrollArgs
{
    // Scroll event argument
    private int mTop;
    private bool mTracking;
    public BetterListBoxScrollArgs(int top, bool tracking)
    {
        mTop = top;
        mTracking = tracking;
    }
    public int Top 
    {
        get { return mTop; }
    }
    public bool Tracking 
    {
        get { return mTracking; }
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что теперь нам будет проще добавлять наш улучшенный ListBox только через код.

Делается это несложно:

```
var list1 = new BetterListBox();

list1.Width = 200;
list1.Height = 200;

Controls.Add(list1);
```

Теперь подпишемся на событие:

```
list1.Scroll += BetterListBox1_Scroll;
```

Где `BetterListBox1_Scroll` - это наш обработчик события:

```
void BetterListBox1_Scroll(object s, BetterListBoxScrollArgs e)
{
    // здесь будут наши обновления других списков
}
```

Обновим остальные списки:

```
void BetterListBox1_Scroll(object s, BetterListBoxScrollArgs e)
{
    list4.TopIndex = list3.TopIndex = list2.TopIndex = list1.TopIndex;
}
```

Готово! Некоторые моменты проверил лично, но не все, поэтому могут возникнуть непредвиденные трудности, на счет них либо спрашивать, либо искать в интернетах, а знающим править найденную ошибку.

P.s.: Если есть возможность и желание, то лучше воспользоваться готовыми решениями, которое подразумевают то же самое и более пригодны для ТЗ, то есть [таблицами](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagrid-control-overview-windows-forms).

[Источник](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread168034.html)